# How to add a $geoWithin constraint to a query in parse server?

Tags: mongodb-query, parse-server

I tried to add a `$geoWithin` constraint to a `Parse.Query` like so:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("MyCollection");
var jsonQuery = query.toJSON();

jsonQuery.where.location = {
    "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [
            [geoPoint.longitude, geoPoint.latitude],
            10 / 6371.0
        ]
    }
};

query.withJSON(jsonQuery);
```

It throws the error:

> bad $geoWithin value; $polygon should contain at least 3 GeoPoints.

The reason is apparently that Parse Server's [Mongo Transformer](https://github.com/Ciircles/parse-server/blob/8034f7386bd5a104c58bf0380d45347e32da3ce5/src/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js#L906) only accepts a polygon parameter with `$geoWithin`.

How can I add a query constraint that limits the results to documents with a `location` field within a certain radius in km of a geo coordinate?

Comment: How is the geometry in your database?

Comment: @AndréClaudino Using parse-server I assume the location field index is "2d". The values are stored as lat and long values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Parse Server did not support this type of query. But since `Parse Server` is an open s[ource project on Github](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server), I added the feature*.

The code in the question works and the same can be achieved setting the new `sorted` parameter in geo queries to `false`:

```
var location = new Parse.GeoPoint(37.708813, -122.526398);
var distance = 5;
var sorted = false;

var query = new Parse.Query(MyCollection);
query.withinKilometers("location", location, distance, sorted);
```

**Feature not yet available as of Parse Server v2.8.2 and JS SDK v1.11.1, waiting for merge of pull requests.*